# What does "-(void)" mean in this function declaration? `-(void)awakeFromNib`

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How come whenever I have to use awakeFromNib protocol I have to put it in this format?

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
```

What is the need for -(void)?

Comment: Perhaps you should put xcode and objective-c as tags for your question?

Comment: If you find an answer useful, mark it as so by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `-(void)` is used in the declaration of the method. Presumably, you are defining it for someone else to call, rather than calling it yourself.

The `-` sign indicates that the method is an instance method, as opposed to a class method. It requires an object to call it, and instance variables of the object are available to it inside its definition.

The `(void)` indicates the return type. This method doesn't return anything, so its result can't be assigned to anything.

Comment: Just `(void)` is valid in objective c?

Answer (score 8):

think of it this way

say you have a Class you created that is called "Math"

and this class has a method called "calculate". It's type as

```
-(int)calculate {
2+2;
return 2+2;
}
```

When you alloc the class and initialize the object  and perform the "calculate method on that object, it's going to do the calculation 2+2 and it will return the result, 4.

If you tried

```
-(void)calculate {
2+2;
}
```

it wouldn't do anything, it would just have that 2+2 information stored in the method but the calculation would never occur.

Answer (score 2):

Because the method does not return anything, and giving a void return type is how you declare that in C and Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

(void) marks the return type - in this case, void means it's returning nothing.

If it was instead -(int)awakeFromNib, you'd be expected to return an integer.
The meaning of the return value (if any) should be explained in the documentation.